# Why is read.csv getting wrong classes?

Tags: r, dataframe, csv, read.csv

I have to read a big .csv file and read.csv is taking a while. I read that I should use read.csv to read a few rows, get the column classes, and then read the whole file. I tried to do that:

```
read.csv(full_path_astro_data,
         header=TRUE,
         sep=",",
         comment.char="",
         nrow=100,
         stringsAsFactors=FALSE) %>%
  sapply(class) -> col.classes

df_astro_data <- read.csv(full_path_astro_data,
                          header=TRUE,
                          sep=",",
                          colClasses=col.classes,
                          comment.char="",
                          nrow=47000,
                          stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

But then I got an error message:

```
Error in scan(file = file, what = what, sep = sep, quote = quote, dec = dec,  : 
  scan() expected 'an integer', got '0.0776562500000022'
```

It looks like a column that contains numeric (double?) data was incorrectly classified as integer. This could be because some numeric columns have many zeros at the beginning. So I tried to increase the number of rows in the first read.csv command, but that did not work. One solution I found was to do

```
col.classes %>% 
   sapply(function(x) ifelse(x=="integer", "numeric", x)) -> col.classes
```

With this the file is read much faster than without specifying column classes. Still, it would be best if all columns were classified correctly.

Any insights?

Thanks

Comment: Tip - use ``fread`` from ``data.table`` and you won't have to worry about any of this & it's much faster.

Comment: This question is a bit odd tbh. My best guess here is that the respective column contains integers for quite some time before the first non-integer numeric pops up - which is impossible to tell though without data. You can get around this by either replacing integer with numeric in `col.classes` (as you've done) or by reading the whole csv from the start. Indeed, some packages provide better methods anyway, so why do you want  `read.csv`?

Answer (score 3):

I suspect you are correct that in your row sample some columns contain only integers, but outside your row sample they contain non-integers. This is a common problem with large files. You need to either increase your row sample size or explicitly specify column type for certain columns where you see this happening.

It should be noted that `readr`'s `read_csv` does this row sampling automatically. From the docs: "all column types will be imputed from the first 1000 rows on the input. This is convenient (and fast), but not robust. If the imputation fails, you'll need to supply the correct types yourself." You can do that like this:

```
read_csv( YourPathName, 
          col_types = cols(YourProblemColumn1 = col_double(), 
                           YourProblemColumn2 = col_double())
)
```